# Credentials Not working Unless domain uppercase on only 1 server

Tags: powershell, server, credentials, networkcredentials

I have a script that runs from one server against 3 (supposedly) identical servers.
in the script the credentials are as follows:

```
$account = "domain\first.last"
$PASSWORD = ConvertTo-SecureString PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force
$UNPASSWORD = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential $account, $PASSWORD
```

On 2 of three server the domain being in lowercase works fine. but on one of my servers suddenly it will not accept the credentials unless the domain is typed in UPPER case letters.

Can anyone explain this? The settings on the affected server have not been touched, but the application it runs has been upgraded on all 3 servers recently.

All 3 servers should be identical.

Comment: I would look at how these servers are domain joined

Comment: All 3 boxes appears to be joined to the domain in the same way.

Comment: @Matthew : a machine is either domain joined or not. You can't "check how a machine is domain joined" since it either exists in AD or it doesn't (and assuming that there is a working trust between the machine and a the domain)